# Zoom only in x but not in y direction?

Tags: python, bokeh

when displaying a figure produced by Bokeh in a web browser, it is possible to zoom in. Is it possible to zoom only in x-direction, say, but not in y-direction?

I am thinking about displaying a time series f(t) where the range for f(t) is small and fixed, but the data is present for long periods of time t. It would be great to be able to focus in on particular moments in the history of the data, while maintaining the whole range of f(t) values.

Many thanks,

Hans

Comment: I think this is currently an open issue https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/issues/132'

Comment: In the latest 0.7 release, you can hover your mouse over the x-axis and scroll the mouse wheel to zoom in only the x-direction. Likewise for the y-axis.

Comment: @jkitchen can't confirm this. Does it require any particular tools activated?

Answer (score 7):

I just added a PR for this feature: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/pull/508

It should be in master tonight, and part of the upcoming release. Basically it adds new tool names: `xpan`, `ypan`, `xwheel_zoom`, `ywheel_zoom`

Sorry this took so long, sometimes small but important things get lost in the shuffle.

Comment: For other people coming here: If using tool shortcuts, the above are the solution ('xpan', 'ypan', etc.). If using actual `Tool` instances, one has to pass `dimensions=['width']` or something similar to the parameter, e.g., `bokeh.models.WheelZoomTool(dimensions=['width'])`.

Comment: Note that the online docs are currently out of date and incorrect regarding the `dimensions` parameter. Should be fixed by the next release.

Comment: Can someone please show a complete example as an answer to the question?

Comment: There are several in the repo, e.g. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-2.4/examples/plotting/file/range_tool.py

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** As of Bokeh 0.5 these [tools](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/user_guide.html#tools) are now available: `xpan, ypan, xwheel_zoom, ywheel_zoom`.

---

As Philliproso pointed out above, this is still an open issue; we hope to have it implemented within the next couple of releases.

In the meantime, the box_zoom tool can prescribe zoom boundaries visually.